# Build Existing Grails project in Gradle?

Tags: java, grails, gradle, build.gradle, ggts

I already have an existing Grails project in GGTS, now i want to build that project in Gradle.
Any solution how to do it step by step.
I have tried so may versions of online solution, but not working.
I am new to Grails and Gradle.

Comment: Grails 2 had it's own build system, Grails 3 uses gradle. Grails 2 you can run commands outside the IDE with the grails wrapper `./grailsw run-app`. What are you trying to accomplish? What guides have you tried? What specific version of Grails are you using?

Comment: i am using Grails 2.4.4 . with GGTS IDE. i have Gradle 3.0 installed on my system.

Comment: I'd question why you want to use gradle in grails 2 - while possible, I don't see a reason to.

Answer (score 1):

The gradle plugin for Grails 2 (https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/issues/149) seems to not support gradle over 2.2.x - Downgrade gradle and try using it.